# How do I output an array of strings to a file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to write a list into .txt file?

Here is my code:

```
num_of_mangoes[]
for i in range(shops):
  num_of_mangoes.append([])
   for j in range(fruits):
     num_of_mangoes[i].append(j)
 
return num_of_mangoes
```

Additional information:

1. number of shops = `200000`
2. Number of fruits = `500`

Comment: What have you tried? What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: I did not try to output into a text file.. I am here to get help

Comment: You need to have tried what you need help with first. Many tutorials exist on writing to file. You got an answer this time, but please in the future make sure you're making an effort to learn on your own first. That's an expectation here.

Comment: Thank you, I will look up online for resources before posting here. I thought this would be my resource!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the actual code is:

```py
num_of_mangoes = []
for i in range(shops):
    num_of_mangoes.append([])
    for j in range(fruits):
        num_of_mangoes[i].append(j)
```

I suggest using the [json module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) to export it to a file

```py
import json


with open("num_of_mangoes.txt", "w") as file:
    json.dump(file, num_of_mangoes)
```

If you want to read your list back from the file you can do:

```py
with open("num_of_mangoes.txt", "r") as file:
    num_of_mangoes = json.load(file)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this instead:

```
# we'll use this module later on
import json

# define the number of shops and fruits    
shops, fruits = 200000, 500

# create the "num_of_mangoes" list using a list comprehension
num_of_mangoes = [[j for j in range(fruits)] for i in range(shops)]

# open the file (create if not exists), write to it, then close it
f = open("num_of_mangoes.txt", "w")
# NOTE: the "separators" and "indent" arguments are used to minify the json
f.write(json.dumps(num_of_mangoes, separators = (',', ':'), indent = 0))
f.close()
```

Here's the one-liner version of the same code:

```
import json; with open("num_of_mangoes.txt", "w") as f: f.write(json.dumps([[j for j in range(500)] for i in range(200000)], separators = (',', ':'), indent = 0))
```

Minified:

```
import json;with open("num_of_mangoes.txt","w") as f:f.write(json.dumps([[j for j in range(500)] for i in range(200000)],separators=(',',':'),indent=0))
```

**WARNING:** your JSON file is going to be (ridiculously) large, don't open it using a text editor like Atom, it'll probably freeze your computer, use the `cat`, `head` or `tail` commands instead.

**WARNING:** given that you have `200000` (two hundred thousand) shops, this list will take a while to create, I'd advise that you lower that number for testing purposes.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: You're very welcome.